# Freeing objects in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP in PHP (normally write software). I have read that when an object goes out of scope it will be free'd so there is no need to do it manually. However, if I have a script like:

```
while ($var == 1) {
    $class = new My_Class();
    //Do something

    if ($something) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This script will loop until `$something` is true which in my mind will create a lot of instances of `$class`. Do I need to free it at the end of each iteration? Will the same var name just re-reference itself? If I do need to free it, would `unset()` suffice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign a new instance to a variable, the old instance referenced by that variable (if any) has its [reference count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) decreased. In this case the refcount will become zero. Since it is no longer referenced it will be automatically cleaned up.

From PHP 5.3 there is a proper [garbage collector](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) that can also handle circular references. You can enable it by calling [`gc_enable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-enable.php).

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be necessary to `unset()` it in this context, as it will be overwritten on each iteration of the loop. Depending on what other actions are taking place in the `while` loop, it may be preferable to assign the `$class` outside the loop.  Does `$class` change on each iteration?

```
$class = new My_Class();
while ($var ==1)
{
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless:  the loop will be running a very long time; you anticipate a high number of concurrent users; or there are limited resources on the server (i.e. self-host, VPS/shared, etc), then you don't need to worry about it.  In any scenario where the script won't be running for very long (less than 5 seconds), anything you try to do to free memory is going to be less effective than PHP's garbage collector.

That said, if you need to clear the reference (because of one of the aforementioned scenarios, or because you like to be tidy), you can set the variable to null or use the `unset` function.  That will remove the reference and PHP's garbage collector will clean it up because there are no more references to it.

Comment: The script will potentially be running for days / weeks. It doesn't do much inside but will be running non the less. I used this approach instead of a cron because the script needs to be running all the time but teh time it takes in the loop is variable and can't be guranteed which a cron needs .. and Yes, Im on a VPS.

Comment: Then you should probably `unset` or set the reference to null.  I would also suggest that you carefully examine the structure of MyClass and any child objects it instantizes.  To completely set the reference count to 0 (and allow the garbage collector to recover related resources), you'll want to ensure that no child class references the parent MyClass.  Otherwise, even though you have no local references, there will still be a pointer to MyClass and it won't be freed until the end of the request.